# Where are the parentheses in an explicit convertion written?

Tags: c#

Why is an explicit conversion written like

```
int operand = 1;
byte result = (byte)operand;
```

instead of

```
int operand = 1;
byte result = byte(operand);
```

?

Is `byte` in the former treated as an operator?

Is `byte` in the latter  treated as a method?

Thanks.

Comment: Because the designers of the language (or the one it evolved from) chose this particular syntax.

Comment: Why was it designed that way, instead of being used like a method?

Comment: Because that's how they designed it.  Pascal does it the other way.  There is no right or wrong, and asking "why" is pointless.

Comment: what are the cons and pros? Meaningful now?

Comment: I understand what you are asking. Why did you ask "what are the cons and pros" istead of "what the pros and cons"?  It's arbitrary. There really aren't too many -- arguably the Pascal style reduces parentheses which is potentially stylistically more pleasing, but really SO is not a good place to ask this sort of question.  You'd have to ask the original designer of the syntax.

Comment: This question is like: "Why do we declare variables in C# like `int x;` while in VB it's `Dim x As Integer`?" It's a matter of C# syntax that is derived from C/C++ no more.

Comment: The syntax comes from C, it was a bad design decision then, and we're stuck with it now. There's not much more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is indeed an (unary) operator. You can even create your own ones using following syntax:

```
public static explicit operator MyType(OtherType t)
{
    // return instance of MyType
}
```

Comment: Why was it designed that way, instead of being used like a method?

Answer (score 1):

It's written inside of the parameters. It comes from C/C++. There's no method called `byte`. It's an explicit cast defined by .NET. `byte` is a C# keyword/alias for `System.Byte`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `byte` is not method? then what is it?

Comment: I know it is a type. But here Is it an operator?

Comment: It is an operator not a method. So perhaps they chose to use a non-method syntax to make that clear. Other unary operators sit out front and do not require parentheses around the targer.